# Cannot read property 'split' of undefined Javascript

Tags: javascript, algolia

I'm using Algolia instantsearch and I'm trying to remove `public` from the image url so that it can display the image. The url looks like this `public/photos/436Rga0UafNBJkBe6b5X0DJL49jcife687sqqgeI.jpeg`on Algolia indices attributes, so the final url looks like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/public/photos/436Rga0UafNBJkBe6b5X0DJL49jcife687sqqgeI.jpeg`. I want to remove that `public` so it can be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/photos/436Rga0UafNBJkBe6b5X0DJL49jcife687sqqgeI.jpeg`. I have tried to use `split('public').pop()` but I get an error `Cannot read property 'split' of undefined  Javascript`. How can I replace that?

```
search.addWidget(
    instantsearch.widgets.hits({
        container: '#hits',
        templates: {
            empty: 'No results',
            item: function(item) {
                return `
                <div>
                  <img src="${window.location.origin}/storage/${item.products_photos.split('public').pop()}" alt="img" class="algolia-thumb-result">
                    </div> 
                `;
            }
        }
    })
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to make sure that `item.products_photos` exists, a simple fix would be

```
<img src="${window.location.origin}/storage/${(item.products_photos || '').split('public').pop()}" alt="img" class="algolia-thumb-result">
```

Comment: This doesn't display the image , the url looks like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/` @dave

Comment: then you need to look at `item` and see what is actually in it, right now there doesn't seem to be a `.products_photos` in it

Answer (score 2):

You can use replace :

```js
var test = "someAdress/public/someText.jpeg";
test = test.replace("public/","");
console.log(test);
```

So try this :

```
<img src="${window.location.origin}/storage/${item.products_photos.replace("public/","");}" alt="img" class="algolia-thumb-result">
```